# Raise browser window when click link in non-browser app

Tags: gnome, firefox, window

When I click on a link in a non-browser application (e.g., mail or chat), my default browser (Firefox) opens a new tab and goes to the desired site. That part is fine. What *used* to also happen was that the browser window would open if it were minimized, and 'raise' (come forward) so that it was not obscured by any other windows. But something has changed, and it no longer does that. What setting controls this, and how can I set it back to what it was?

Ubuntu 17.10, Gnome 3.26.2, Firefox 60.0.1